# ultra simple jquery tabs multiple tab problem

Tags: jquery, tabs, controls

I have a question about ultra simple jquery tabs.
I use this script: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HX5KZ/2/

When I duplicate same tab with html code, the second tabs button open first tab-container.
When I tried to change "switch_tabs" function and i tried to built each function structure.
But couldnt change this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is that you have multiple DOM elements with the same ID.

ID has to be unique. try using different ID's for the second content elements